# How to change the title/branding in the drupal user registration form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to know how to change the branding of the Drupal user registration form. I don't remember how I changed that earlier. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

[please check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL0wM.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the form with `hook_form_alter`.

In the `template.php` of your theme, you should add:

```
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register') {
    drupal_set_title(t('Create student Details'));
  }
  elseif ($form_id == 'user_pass') {
    drupal_set_title(t('Request new password'));
  }
  elseif ($form_id == 'user_login') {
  drupal_set_title(t('Log in'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I had an error with a menu I created earlier and it had overrun the default title/branding. I figured it out and solved it. Thanks a bunch.